# Undo page-wide applied opacity in a transparent box

Tags: html, css

Real code is much more complicated, but I think the snippet illustrates the issue well enough.

I have a background-video playing (here just background, same result) and on top of that there is a watch(square here). The watch's dial is transparent, meaning through the dial you see the background video. Now, the background-video has rgba(0,0,0,0.2) on it to make it darker. Inside the dial, I do not want that rgba(0,0,0,0.2) applied - I want the original video without that effect. I have no idea if that is possible with css.

So for the snippet, How can I make the square show the full black color without just setting its color. Since in the real code, that is not an option (as mentioned, transparent and a video is passing through the box)

```css
.container{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* square background should be black, so no opacity on it */
.square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are looking for. You can use a large spread shadow on the box to get this affect.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1454496522488-7a8e488e8606?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8bW91bnRhaW58ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60');

}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 50vw rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a cool idea, thanks for showing! But I want the the square to be transparent and the rest around it have a back shadow applied, if that makes sense? This way I can only apply colour, right?

Comment: @Leviathan Yeah that should be possible using this method. I've updated the answer to more clearly show that.